# Converting Currency Method: <identifier> expected May split declaration into declaration and assignement

Tags: java, variable-assignment

What's wrong with this code?

```
private void jButtonConvActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    double Algerian_Dinars = Double.parseDouble(jtxtConvert.getText());
    if (jCombCrrency.getSelectedItem().equals("USA"))
    {
        double US_Dollar = 0,00905365; /*here is the error???*/
        String cconvert1 = String.format("N%.2f",Algerian_Dinars * US_Dollar);
        jlblConvert.setText(cconvert1);
```

Comment: @Tom Please don't edit and bump old questions, especially not ones so bad as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use comma in doubles in Java.

```
double US_Dollar = 0,00905365;
                    ^
```

I am assuming you missed out decimal instead like:

```
double US_Dollar = 0.00905365;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.